# Our App Detail page is still pending after a few weeks. High ratings is needed

Tags: facebook

We have all the details correct but still pending.

The message says: "Your App Detail page is live and available in search. Your app does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be approved for listing in the App Center at this time."

So the question I need to know is: how do we get High Ratings? How can people vote/rate our game?

And is this all that's needed to be approved?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem is wide known.

The Solution , as it wisorked for a friend,  to have your App Live Up and Running.
Once it has enough engagement Facebook will review it for App Center listing.

Be aware of common Submission Mistakes, as those will keep your App unlisted.

A brief look at the [App Center Guideline](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/) will enlighten you more.

Hope it Helps

Comment: Thanks! So what is the magic number of user engagement before they will look at reviewing our App listing for the app centre? Is the magic number hundreds or thousands before they will look at us? No one seems to know what the number is. :-)

Comment: Nobody knows, thats the facebook crap!